# Why is my character transparent in the render?

Tags: transparency

[image]when i render my character is transparent? Why? I have tried changing the setting under the block tab. I started having the problem after hid them for a separate render but when i unhid it it came back like this

Comment: Think of your question from the point of view of someone who has never seen your project and knows nothing about it. With the provided information and images there is not much we can learn. If this is a problem with the materials, it would help to see the materials for he character. If it is a rendering issue, it would help to see the nodes for compositing and render layers. If the character is not visible to camera, it would help to see the settings for light ray visibility. Please [edit] your post and help those users who might help you with your issue

Comment: i'm not sure if this is connected but you might have accidentally made it a shadow catcher, tough it is hard to tell from your question.